# JFugue 5.0 can't control volume

Tags: java, jfugue

i love jFugue, but i can't control the volume of a pattern.
This 2 patterns, in my laptop, play at the same volume(on the paper the second should be twice louder than the first):

```
        Pattern pattern1 = new Pattern("X[Volume]=8000 C D E");
        new Player().play(pattern1);

        Pattern pattern2 = new Pattern("X[Volume]=16000 C D E");
        new Player().play(pattern2);
```

I'm using jFugue 5.0.9.

Comment: If you downvote... at least explain why...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JFugue 5, the MIDI commands are now invoked through the Function system. To control the coarse volume, try this:

```
Pattern pattern1 = new Pattern(":CON(7, 40) C D E");
new Player().play(pattern1);
Pattern pattern2 = new Pattern(":CON(7, 127) C D E");
new Player().play(pattern2);
```

You may refer to [Differences in JFugue 5.0](http://www.jfugue.org/articles/differences.html) for more information.

Comment: you're right, i was using the <5 way of setting volume. Didn't know that ver 5 introduced that many changes.

Comment: @jjcipher I appreciate your nice answer! Signed, Author of JFugue :)